# Failing to insert data into MS Access database (syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.)

Tags: c#, ms-access, insert, insert-into, ms-access-2016

I wrote this code to insert data into my Microsoft Access database but it is failing and throws this error:

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Here is my code:

```
  // Open the connection to the database.
  connection.Open();
  OleDbCommand dbcmd = new OleDbCommand();
  dbcmd.Connection = connection;

  // Inserting Data.
  dbcmd.CommandText = "insert into ConveyanceBill1 (empname, from) values('" + txtEmployee.Text + "','" + txtFrom.Text + "')";
  dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Added!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
  connection.Close();
```

But if I change this line:

```
// Inserting Data.
dbcmd.CommandText = "insert into ConveyanceBill1 (empname, from) values('" + txtEmployee.Text + "','" + txtFrom.Text + "')";
```

To this Line:

```
// Inserting Data.              
dbcmd.CommandText = "insert into ConveyanceBill1 (empname, designation) values('" + txtEmployee.Text + "','" + txtDesignation.Text + "')";
```

It works flawlessly. I can't find why it is not working.Here is my database table in Design view:

[image: Designview of Database Table]

I tried a lot, but I still don't get why it is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FROM` is a [reserved keyword](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321266) in Microsoft OLE DB Provider. You might wanna use it with square brackets like `[FROM]`. But as a best practice, change it to *non*-reserved word.

### But more important

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

```
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(var dbcmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    dbcmd.CommandText = "insert into ConveyanceBill1 (empname, from) values(?, ?)";
    dbcmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtEmployee.Text;
    dbcmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtFrom.Text;
   
    connection.Open();
    int effectedRows = dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if(effectedRows > 0)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Added!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this by 100 points - this is absolutely **crucial** and everyone learning to program with databases **should read and embrace this!**

Comment: @marc_s Thank you very much. Those are important words for me to hear that such a person/user like you. I _really_ appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

**"from"** is a reserved word for Microsoft access change it to non reserved word such as **"desfrom"** and it should work fine.

Comment: Don't you think you are a little bit late, like more than an hour? :)

Comment: Hahah, I found it so I answered it. :)